# Comparing two Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Both List A and List

List A = new List();
List B = new List();

For the sake of simplicity, I have mentioned the Products in each List. Te numbers here are referring to the Product ID.

```
  List A contains 1,2,3,4,5

  List B contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I want to know the code in c# asp.net that will compare the two lists, and synchronizing them. Meaning if List B had some more Products (lets say 19,20) it copy 19,20 to List A.

Lets say it was a List, how would I compare the qty attribute. I have to check if the same product ID is in both lists. Then it would check the qty attribute. It would synch them both.

Comment: Your edit has completely changed the question!  What does "synch them both" mean, if you have a product in list A with `{ Id=1, Qty=10 }` and one in list B with `{ Id=1, Qty=5 }`.  What would be synced?

Comment: Provide a better example for the edited question. I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: actually i am synchronizing between the session of a shopping cart, and the cart items in the database. i first load the results from db and save it to a session.....then after user logs out...i want to save the session to the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this is the most efficient solution (I'm sure there must be a better Linq method for this )...

```
c = A.Except(B).Union(B.Except(A)).ToList();
```

Comment: Be careful, though, when you use this kind of methods on lists of custom objects. These use the default comparer (which in turn uses the `Equals` method (which by default does a `ReferenceEquals`)) to determine if two elements are correct. If you have some custom equality code in your classes, i.e. two products are the same if they have the same ProductID, etc, it's good to test this kind of code as much as possible for stupid edge cases.

Comment: Yeah, fair comment - with `int` this is fine, but for a `Product` class it may not be.  That said, the question's been totally changed now, so who knows what the real answer may be...

Answer (score 2):

```
List<T> result = firstList.Except(secondList).ToList()
```

And you could need to implement an `EqualityComparer<T>` on your class to ensure equality on your objects.

Comment: `Except` will return the elements in the first that are not in the second (from the example given it's not clear if intersect or except is needed)

Comment: @SWeko: from the example 4 and 5 are the numbers expected to be returned, which is everything in A that isn't in B. So `Except` is the correct answer.

Comment: @SWeko: beat me to it!  My answer took this into account, but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way...

Comment: @Matt Ellen: the (original) question specifically asked for elements that were unique to *either* list, not just to the first.  Although the example may have been poor, the intent was clear.

Comment: @SWeko: the original question wanted to "find out the elements **not** common in both", so returning elements that **are** common in both is wrong.

Comment: actually i am synchronizing between the session of a shopping cart, and the cart items in the database. i first load the results from db and save it to a session.....then after user logs out...i want to save the session to the db

Comment: Even after your explanation I can't understand why you need to "merge" this lists? Can't you loop through the user's cart and write each item to the database?